# How to drop rows from a data frame where ALL values are null

Tags: python, pandas

I can't figure out how to drop rows from my data frame where ALL of the values in that row are null. I've read in my csv file, but am unsure where to go from there.

```
employee = pd.read_csv('core_data.csv') 
employee = employee.replace('\\N',np.nan)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [pandas.DataFrame.dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

```py
employee.dropna(axis=0, how='all', inplace=True)
```

Comment: What do the "how" and "inplace" conditions do?

Comment: `how` determines if the row should be deleted if it has at least 1 missing value, or all missing values. `inplace` modified the dataframe directly.

Answer (score 0):

read the doc, it is explained in the first lines:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

```
employee.dropna(axix=0, how='all')
```

how='all' is the argument you are looking for, it means that it deletes the row (axis=0) only if all values are nan